# Can a wizard with the False Focus feat use a reliquary weapon as a divine focus, and what value is it considered if so?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, holy-symbol

My character is a wizard that worships Milani and uses the [False Focus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/false-focus/) feat to cast most spells without the need of components, and also loves firearms.

I recently discovered the [Craft Reliquary Arms and Shields](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/create-reliquary-arms-and-shields/) feat that can give a weapon the same properties as a holy symbol. The thing is : the value of a holy symbol rarely has any relevance except for the False Focus feat and thus I have no idea what value a reliquary weapon has for the False Focus feat.

Is a reliquary weapon a valid divine focus for an arcane spellcaster with the False Focus feat ? If so, what is its equivalent gp value as a divine focus ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Craft Reliquary Arms and Shields feat has this line:

> This increases the item’s price by 250 gp.

as well as

> The item becomes a reliquary and can be used as a holy (or unholy) symbol divine focus of your deity.

So, you'd figure out what the gp value of the magic weapon or shield was, and then you could use it for False Focus.  Do note the

> (maximum 100 gp)

line in False Focus, though.